# Dropdown inside an IFrame closes when clicked outside the IFrame

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have a main program (some sort of testing control panel) that runs another program in an IFrame. In some sorts, this is similar to Storybook. The reason to have an IFrame is to provide some separation between the program that is tested (which may do what it wants with its DOM) and the host w/ the control panel = buttons & co.

I was surprised to observe that if I have in the IFrame a dropdown, and I click somewhere but OUTSIDE that IFrame => the dropdown closes. So practically the code in the IFrame has reacted to an event that happened in the parent window. (NOTE: the page in the IFrame comes from the same domain).

This is something that I don't bothers me. Any ideas why this happens and what can I do to avoid this? So I'd like the code in the IFrame to stop receiving/reacting events that correspond to actions that I do outside the IFrame.

Comment: The "blur" event fires on any active element when it loses focus, which can happen as a result of actions outside the current window.   The only way to avoid this is to have your dropdown not close on blur, but on some more specific event restricted to your iframe (capturing a click event on the iframe body for example.)

Comment: Thanks for the comment. So there is a "focus" issue, as in "focus is global among all windows, i.e. browser windows + other windows". Unfortunately the dropdown is not mine. It belongs to the app that is being tested and currently frozen. For me, the app is a black box: I don't know what's in it.

Comment: OK, yep, in that case what you're asking for is not possible.